# MySQL: Most efficient way to count records added today

Tags: mysql, performance

This is the MySQL table structure that I have:

```
itemID (BIGINT)
userID (BIGINT)
wasAdded (DATETIME)
```

I need to get the number of items introduced in the current day, by the *X* userID

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way would be to add an index that covers `userID` *and* `wasAdded`, then you can do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE userID = 'X' AND wasAdded BETWEEN CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '00:00:00') AND CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '23:59:59');
```

This shouldn't even need to read from the table, as all the data it needs is in the index.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick :

```
SELECT COUNT(itemID) FROM 'tableName' WHERE TO_DAYS(wasAdded) = TO_DAYS(NOW()) AND userID = X
```

However, make sure to have an index on `wasAdded` and `userID` !

Comment: Are you sure MySQL will be able to use an index on wasAdded if you use TO_DAYS? If you think it will, I'd be interested in reading a reference

Comment: No I'm not, you're absolutely right. Using TO_DAYS() will make the index useless regarding to my query. Thanks for the correction !